# Average Price per column within different tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm stumped in trying to complete a problem I was tasked in getting solved.

I'm tasked with doing the following: Calculate the average cost for different products and group them by the category of the product.

How can I do this against different tables?

Comment: If I wrote a really nice but long solution query, took a screenshot of it, and added that image as an answer, would you be annoyed about the unnecessary transcription effort? **Please don't use images of data**, just copy/paste some data into the question and format it using the `{}` button in the toolbar. ps: You can use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to create ascii tables.

Comment: @TheCuriousProgrammer . . . From what I calculate, Postgres is right.  Please elaborate on how you calculate your "ideal" solution.

Comment: @Used_By_Already Sorry about that, StackOverflow noob here. I'll definitely use this going forward.

Comment: You don't need your where clause. You have joined the entire supply table, so every selling_price is already part of the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff So my "ideal" solution is produced by adding the 'selling_price' of each product that is related to a category.


For example: Category 1 has product(1), product(2), product(3). Therefore, I'm doing (($4) + ($10 + $5) + ($5 + $12) / 3) = $12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see.  You want the "average" per "product", not over all the products.  So, you need to calculate this yourself using `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT p.category AS category_id,
       SUM(s.selling_price::numeric) / COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id)
FROM product p JOIN
     supply s
     ON p.product_id = s.product_id
GROUP BY p.category;
```

Comment: Ahhhhh! That works perfectly. Thank you so much for your quick assistance.